# Variable is used before its assignment typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a set of async tasks which is independent of each other. I have two questions, when considering the below code.

```
const parallelTasks: any = []    
let email:string

//parallelTasks.push(otherPromises)

const PromiseTask1 = new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
         //some code
         email = await GetEmail(connection)
         resolve('')
    })
 parallelTasks.push(PromiseTask1)
 
 // Scenario 1
 await Promise.all(parallelTasks)
 console.log(email) //this is giving me lint error "variable email is used before assignment"
  
 // Scenario 2
 Promise.all(parallelTasks).then(()=>{
     console.log(email) //this is working fine
 })
```

if i declare just like below, its not showing me any lint error. my questions are

```
let email: any
```

1. Is **any** includes Promise type as well?
2. Just consider am using scenario 1, Is **await Promise.all()** blocks the execution of all its below code, if yes, then I should not be getting the lint error when i used **email: string**. if no then, I Shouldnt be getting the value of email in console right. but surprisingly I got the resolved value. what am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Re #1

Yes, `any` includes any type, including `Promise`.

### Re #2

I think you mean you're getting:

> Variable 'email' is used before being assigned.(2454)

from the line using `email` in code similar to this:

```typescript
(async () => {
    const parallelTasks: any = []    
    let email:string

    //parallelTasks.push(otherPromises)

    const PromiseTask1 = new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
            //some code
            email = await GetEmail(/*connection*/)
            resolve('')
        })
    parallelTasks.push(PromiseTask1)
    
    // Scenario 1
    await Promise.all(parallelTasks)
    console.log(email) //this is giving me error 
})();

async function GetEmail() {
    return "foo";
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/BQQwzgngdgxgBMAlHAvAPjgbwFBz3GAeyjABc4AHEAJxABs6BTOgFXAGswAuOEKCVHADaAXXxxc+JuUYBbEAEs6XMtQVQA5tkl4A9Lqq0GzNmE4A6CgFcwAC2CFStxtQAK1QrIVhGYRNvEiEnJ3T29GU3YARkEoRgB3OFCvH1BIWGBqX0I6ADdGABosgCtGGFJEdBxxGvx9ME9GAkIAE0YdWvw5RTpBEHjFcgBxRlIAUXklYF0AKiC48oViGd1-TpqshrzGYAByXbXOgF9DvEN6JlYOMEsbe2TwyKjTiXF9OABlGEYoGiW4KIdfqDJIeFKMcwXYDnYxXMx+DpBLYQuiEDTAbpKZD6JzeOB4jQKXLqDRwWRNFweagSE5IADc2nA0HgADMrLBSEsoHARuNJnQkFgOllSFZqNyAEQswiECUMo5AA)

If so, it's just that you've hit a limit on TypeScript's ability to determine that `email` has been assigned to. You're right, it **has** been assigned to, but it's done too indirectly for TypeScript to see it.

There are at least two ways to deal with that.

#### The first way

You could *use* the result of `Promise.all`, by removing your extra unnecessary `new Promise` call and using `GetEmail` directly:

```typescript
(async () => {
    const parallelTasks: any = [];

    parallelTasks.push(GetEmail(/*connection*/))
    
    const [email] = await Promise.all(parallelTasks);
    console.log(email); // No error now
})();

async function GetEmail() {
    return "foo";
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/BQQwzgngdgxgBMAlHAvAPjgbwFBz3GAeyjABc4AHEAJxABs6BTOgFXAGswAuOEKCVHADaAXQDc2XPiq0GzNmE4A6CgFcwAC2ABxRqQCiAWxABLOsAD0AKiJQojGKRPErFxIil5PBYmWGNjMxFBEAB3U3IABWpCQxMwRiV6cxlk+Q4wRAl8HxJCJiU6QgBzYADTOiy4Cws4ADlCOEZqGOo4KEJQ7ABfRCQJbHBoeAAzVVgnYjhdA0DzZBwc6j1Vaig4ACIRwkINiW6gA)

You'd adjust the destructuring to allow for the results of the other tasks you're putting into `parallelTasks`. For instance:

```typescript
parallelTasks.push(task1());
parallelTasks.push(task2());
parallelTasks.push(GetEmail(connection));
parallelTasks.push(task4());
```

then it might be:

```typescript
const [result1, result2, email, result4] = await Promise.all(paralleltasks);
```

or if you didn't need the others, just put `GetEmail(connection)` in at the front and use the original destructuring above (`const [email] = ...`).

#### The second way

You can tell TypeScript that you know `email` will be definitely assigned before you use it, using the [definitely-assigned assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) (`!`):

```typescript
let email!:string;
//       ^
```

Comment: @Ryan - There's no time difference between the two.